# SLR parsing conflicts with epsilon production

Tags: parsing, grammar, lr-grammar

Consider the following grammar

```
S -> aPbSQ | a

Q -> tS | ε

P -> r
```

While constructing the DFA we can see there shall be a state which contains Items

```
Q -> .tS

Q -> .  (epsilon as a blank string)
```

since t    is in     follow(Q) there appears to be a shift - reduce conflict.

Can we conclude the nature of the grammar isn't SLR(1) ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(Please ignore my incorrect previous answer.)

Yes, the fact that you have a shift/reduce conflict in this configuring set is sufficient to show that this grammar isn't SLR(1).